# Attempting to compile FFmpeg 4.2.3 statically for Windows 10 (x86_64), but binaries asks for missing DLLs

Tags: windows-10, ffmpeg, compilation, mingw, msys

I am using Msys MinGW (x86_64) and pulled a snapshot of the latest major release of FFmpeg off of their website. Here is my `./configure` options. I plan to use the binaries on both the computer that I compiled it on, and other Windows computers that I own.

```
./configure --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-chromaprint --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libgme --enable-libmfx --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libilbc --enable-libvpx --enable-libmodplug --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-libtwolame --enable-vapoursynth --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxavs2 --enable-gpl --enable-static --disable-shared
```

[Output of configure script (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/JQLXqhLt)

Output of `uname -a` (in Msys)

```
MINGW64_NT-10.0-18362 <scrubbed> 3.1.4-340.x86_64 2020-05-22 08:28 UTC x86_64 Msys
```

The issue that I'm facing is that despite passing the options `--enable-static` and `--disable-shared`, the executables generated still require `libchromaprint.dll`, `libfdk-aac-2.dll`, and `libgme.dll` to run. What I expected was that FFmpeg would execute independently of any DLL files since I passed those options to `./configure`.

Comment: Even if the ffmpeg build is correct, it's possible some of the supposedly static libraries you're linking with aren't. Can you run the final link command with extra verbosity to see which files are being linked in?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you specify `--enable-static` the shared libraries may be used in cases where no static library was found. You should get warnings from `libtool` regarding this during the build.

So if it looks for `libchromaprint.a` and can't find it it will link with `libchromaprint.dll.a` causing the dependancy on the DLL.

Check the dependancies to see if their static libraries are available (in your case `libchromaprint.a`, `libfdk-aac-2.a`, `libgme.a`).

Comment: I was able to find these files under /mingw64/lib, however, the `*.dll.a` files are found there as well (except for libgme, which does not have an associated libgme.a). What should I do to explicitly tell `./configure` where to look?

Comment: You could try adding `LDFLAGS="-L/mingw64/lib"` to `./configure` to make sure it finds the library.
You should also make sure the DLL can be found via the `PATH` environment variable.
If pkg-config is involved you may also need to set something like `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=<somepath>/lib/pkgconfig`